# Audiokit 4.7 Playgrounds not compiling. error: Couldn't lookup symbols:

Tags: swift-playground, audiokit, swift5

When I run an AudioKit playground that includes live views, XCode is unable to compile the AudioKit UI framework. An example follows:

```
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.addView(__C.NSView) -> ()
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.stackView.modify : Swift.Optional<__C.NSStackView>
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.stackView.getter : Swift.Optional<__C.NSStackView>
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.stackView.setter : Swift.Optional<__C.NSStackView>
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.addLabel(Swift.String) -> __C.NSTextField
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.addTitle(Swift.String) -> ()
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.textField.modify : Swift.Optional<__C.NSTextField>
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.textField.getter : Swift.Optional<__C.NSTextField>
  AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController.textField.setter : Swift.Optional<__C.NSTextField>
  type metadata for AudioKitUI.AKLiveViewController
  type metadata accessor for AudioKitUI.AKOutputWaveformPlot
  AudioKitUI.AKOutputWaveformPlot.__allocating_init(_: Swift.Optional<AudioKit.AKNode>, frame: __C.CGRect, bufferSize: Swift.Int) -> AudioKitUI.AKOutputWaveformPlot
  AudioKitUI.AKSlider.__allocating_init(property: Swift.String, value: Swift.Double, range: Swift.ClosedRange<Swift.Double>, taper: Swift.Double, format: Swift.String, color: __C.NSColor, frame: __C.CGRect, callback: (Swift.Double) -> ()) -> AudioKitUI.AKSlider
  type metadata accessor for AudioKitUI.AKSlider
  AudioKitUI.AKStylist.sharedInstance.unsafeMutableAddressor : AudioKitUI.AKStylist
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC10AudioKitUI20AKLiveViewController
```

The project builds fine and Playgrounds without UI components work okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by going into the general project settings and adding AudioKitUI.framework

More precisely: in the project navigator on the left side of the project in xCode I selected the project AudioKitPlaygrounds. This should then display the project settings with the General tab selected. Then I went down to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and clicked on the plus sign and browsed within the AudioKitPlaygrounds files for AudioKitUI.framework. Add this framework. Build the project again. Then it should work.

[image]